# Install SharePoint 2013 in home laptop

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I want to download and install SharePoint 2013 on my laptop for my personal use. What are the links to get prerequisites to install SharePoint 2013 server and SharePoint 2013 server?

Answer (score 2):

Just wondering,  what is your purpose on setting up SharePoint on your local machine.  If you just want to play around with SharePoint sites I would suggest you to get a free trial on Office 365 account,

This gives you access to create your SharePoint sites and you can learn basic administrative tasks on SharePoint.

Setting up Share Point locally is good only if you are an advanced user/developer/admin and want to build something custom.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/business/what-is-office-365-for-business-FX102997580.aspx

Another option for you would be to get onto [www.cloudshare.com](http://www.cloudshare.com/showcase) and provision a pre-configured SharePoint VM,  this will save you from long installation process and slowing down your machines.

Hope this helps you in some ways.

Comment: This is the best answer so far because it asks "why" and provides alternatives.  Because let's face it, unless you know what you're doing installing SharePoint properly is a daunting task.

Comment: Thanks Derek, I had installed it on my laptop and realized it doesn't really makes sense unless we want to experience installing it .  It slowed down my laptop like anything. It's much better to ho with alternatives ;-)... Just trying to save someone from that pain

Answer (score 1):

What specs does your laptop have? You need at least I would say 12 GB RAM for SharePoint dev environment.

Also, you should consider running SharePoint virtual in an Virtual box machine on Windows Server 2012, since this is where it is designed to run.

Here are the specs: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The least amount of RAM you will need is 8 GB, otherwise it will be a PITA. When using only on a laptop, disable Distributed cache which consumes some RAM and in most cases in the development environment there are more issues with RAM than with CPU (disabling Distributed cache will increase CPU load). Do NOT disable Distributed cache on production.

Also consider using [VMware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware) or any virtualization software, because it is better to not mess with your main operating system on the laptop. Also you can later easily transfer your image to another machine.

Prerequisites are installed automatically. Especially if you use stand-alone installation there is nothing to worry about.

You can download an evaluation version of SharePoint Server at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/hh973397.aspx or click on the right to get Foundation for free. There is also a link provided with system requirements.